# Angular UI-Router controllerAs empty object in tempate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use angular-ui-router and dont understand why `controllerAs` isn't working. When I use `$scope` the data is available in the template but changing to `controllerAs`: 'vm' results in an empty object in the template. Not sure what I'm missing.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('myState', {
        url: '/my-state',
        templateUrl: 'app/myState/myState.html',
        controller: 'myStateController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });

function myStateController(myStateFactory, $scope) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.test = "hello";

    return myStateFactory.getCountriesStates()
    .then(function (response) {
        vm.countriesStates = response.Countries;
    });
}
```

the template:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
{{vm.test}} <!-- empty-->
    <select ng-model="selectedCountry" class="form-control" ng-change="">
        <option value="">Select a country</option>
        <option ng-repeat="country in vm.countriesStates" 
                value="{{country.v}}">{{country.n}}</option> <!-- empty -->  
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/03g2Xo50ZkRJQIVoXNgF?p=preview)

The point is - redundant **return** statement

with this tricky factory:

```
.factory('myStateFactory', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
      getCountriesStates: function() {
        return $timeout(function(){
          return {
            Countries: [{ v: "x", n: "Czech" }, { v: "o", n: "Other"}]
          };
        })
      }
    }
  }])
```

is this controller working as expected, if we skip return

```
function myStateController(myStateFactory, $scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.test = "hello";

  // do not use return
  //return myStateFactory.getCountriesStates()
  myStateFactory.getCountriesStates()
    .then(function(response) {
      vm.countriesStates = response.Countries;
    });
}
myStateController.$inject = ['myStateFactory', '$scope']
```

Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/03g2Xo50ZkRJQIVoXNgF?p=preview)

Comment: Aww, man! Thanks, that's what I get for copy paste in a hurry.

Comment: Great to see that, sir ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router!